# Access inline event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to access onclick handler of an element, if it is specified inline, something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction();return false;">Forgot password?</a>
```

I tried selecting the element than accessing onclick, but it returns undefined:

```
element.onclick
 undefined
```

I can't use jQuery to solve this, only pure JS, is this even possible ?

Comment: what is your expected result....

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, as this sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: you can try `element.getAttribute('onclick')` which will give `myFunction();return false;`

Comment: Actually, your code should work - https://jsfiddle.net/8n2wp44h/ How are you accessing the `anchor` element ?

Comment: Tested on chrome, working (printing the function instead of undefined)

Comment: getAttribute is working for me, thanks!